# Spring boot with multiple database connections

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I made a simple SpringBoot REST application for testing purposes where the tables are in 2 databases, one is Mysql and one is Postgresql. To configure the 2 connections I used the instructions from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases), at point 6 - "Multiple Databases in Spring Boot" and all seemed to be fine, the 2 connections were initiated but only the primary connection works.

So if the Mysql connection is annotated as @Primay only Mysql REST services work, on Postgresql the error for all tables is "**org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: <Entity_Name> is not mapped**". But if I make a single change and set @Primary on the Postgresql connection then all Postgres tables are working and all Mysql tables give the same error(table not mapped).

So somehow I think the right connection is not autoselected based on the package.

**UPDATE**: I found another tutorial [here](https://mmafrar.medium.com/configuring-multiple-data-sources-with-spring-boot-2-and-spring-data-jpa-8e236844e80f) using different database types, I followed the instructions but the result is the same, all tables in the secondary database give the error "**org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: <Entity_Name> is not mapped**". I think the secondary connection is not used, somehow the primary one defaults on the wrong tables but I don't know why.

I uploaded [this](https://github.com/victorqedu/MultipleSpringBootDS) small Github project with my work.
https://github.com/victorqedu/MultipleSpringBootDS

**UPDATE**: In the DAO class a have autowired the constructor and @Autowire is setting the wrong EntityManager(I think this is the source of the problem), could I manually specify the right EntityManager?

```
@Autowired
public AntibiogramaAntibioticeDAOHibernateImpl(EntityManager theEntityManager) {
    entityManager = theEntityManager;
}
```

I also tried the annotation @PersistenceContext on the EntityManager but the result is the same.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

I'm not sure the problem is EntityManagaer or the Session that I obtain from EntityManager.unwrap, seems to be little documentation about this...

Comment: You need to search for multiple databases **with JPA**, which is a different beast. You can find one solution here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

Comment: This is exactly the solution I applied, it does not seem to work.

Comment: have you tried like **public AntibiogramaAntibioticeDAOHibernateImpl(@Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") EntityManager theEntityManager)** you can choose what to autowire with **Qualifier**

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem, if you please add a response I will mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved with [Qualifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-primary) in a short description **if you have multiple same type of beans(like EntityManager) you should use qualifier to wire them.**

Therefore in [your code](https://github.com/victorqedu/MultipleSpringBootDS/blob/bba321ad9c96e0fa66292ac40e342dfa20fb8470/src/main/java/com/web/caido/dao/hospital4/AntibiogramaAntibioticeDAOHibernateImpl.java#L13) you should

```java
 public AntibiogramaAntibioticeDAOHibernateImpl(
@Qualifier("primaryEntityManagerFactory") EntityManager theEntityManager)
```